# Ito Integral and Integration by part

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $f(s,u)$ be a deterministic function. Consider the stochastic integral

$$
X_t = \int_0^tf(t,s)\,dW_s\quad(1).
$$

I want to use the integration by part formula

$$
X_t^2 = X_0^2+2\,\int_0^tX_s\,dY_s+[X,X]_t
$$

but since the extreme of integration in $(1)$ also appears inside the integration I am a little bit confused on how to apply it.

Comment: I think it depends on if $t$ and $s$ are dependent or not.

Comment: I don't understand, $t$ and $s$ are real numbers, what do you mean with $t$ and $s$ being independent or not?

Comment: What if $s$ is a function of $t$? I mean the situation $f(t,s(t))$.

Comment: Ok, I see your point.  They are independent.

Comment: Then I believe you can just apply the formula here. The integration is only about $s$ on $s$ domain, the same as ordinary integration.